# Post record via jQuery and Save in DB by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm having trouble with save records in MySQL DB, Using PHP.
I want to send the info of users by Post's jQuery method and save to the DB .
 
HTML :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <head>
            <script src="popcorn/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#submit").click(function () {
                        var email = $("#email").val();
                        var name = $("#name").val();
                        $.post('/send.php', {
                            email: email,
                            name: name
                        }, function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email"/>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
    </body>
</html>
```

and get the info by PHP in /send.php

PHP :

```
    <?php
      include 'jdf.php';

      $servername = "localhost";
      $username = "popcorn";
      $password = "0201243aa";
      $dbname = "popcorn";

      $created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
      $name =  $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];

      // Create connection
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
      // Check connection
      if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      }

      $sql = "INSERT INTO `popcorn-app`(`id`, `email`, `name`, `created`) VALUES (NULL,$email,$name,$created)";

      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
          echo "New record created successfully";
      } else {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
      }

      $conn->close();
      ?>
```

but my problem is here , when i put the info and POST with jQuery , console got me a error .

```
16:44:43.676 "Error: INSERT INTO `popcorn-app`(`id`, `email`, `name`, `created`) VALUES (NULL,goldast.xps@gmail.com,mohammad,2015-07-30 16:44:47)<br>You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com,mohammad,2015-07-30 16:44:47)' at line 1 "1 post.html:13:5
```

Comment: FYI `<head>` tag is not supposed to be inside a `<body>`.

Comment: Just like the error shows this should be like `INSERT INTO `popcorn-app`(`id`, `email`, `name`, `created`) VALUES (NULL,goldast.xps@gmail.com,mohammad,2015-07-30 16:44:47)` 

`INSERT INTO `popcorn-app`(`id`, `email`, `name`, `created`) VALUES (NULL,'goldast.xps@gmail.com', 'mohammad' ,'2015-07-30 16:44:47')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass string values inside " ".
i.e.`(NULL,'$email','$name','$created')`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line with code below. This should solve your problem.

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `popcorn-app`(`id`, `email`, `name`, `created`) VALUES (NULL,'$email','$name',$created)";
```

This is because email and name should be char or varchar in your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `popcorn-app`(`email`, `name`, `created`) VALUES ('".$email.".,'".$name."','".$created."')";
```

If id is auto-increment then no need to add in query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `popcorn-app`(`email`, `name`, `created`) VALUES ('".$email."','".$name."','".$created."')";
```